# How to set gateway address in /30 network?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iptables

i have /22 network and need /30 network for my virtual machine.
My 22 network is 192.168.20.0/22 and 30 is the same.
Can i get different  from 192.168.20.2 address for server. How could i setup redirecting all outbound traffic to a physical gateway?

Comment: Do you really "_**need** /30 network for my virtual machine_"? A `/30` network can only have two hosts (`00` = Network Address, `01` = Host 1, `10` = Host 2, `11` = Broadcast Address)

Comment: Also, one host with two interfaces that have overlapping networks is asking for trouble... That's probably not going to work. Can you draw a diagram of what you want?

Comment: That's true but having a /22 network doesn't mean having the whole /22 on-link on an interface; as long as all interfaces use smaller non-overlapping subnets, describing the whole system as "a /22 network" makes sense.

Comment: @Attie i am doing lab, where is written "We don’t want you to use the DHCP service of your machine. You’ve got to
configure it to have a static IP and a Netmask in \30." So i have two ways - use nat, but i can not filter traffic from dos attack, because i have no information about source ip.

Comment: "[_Destination NAT_](https://serverfault.com/a/119374/405400)" still provides the original source address... it just modifies the destination. This is the mode that home routers and VM "_NAT'ed_" interfaces typically operate in.